# Is this allowed to use dlopen() and dlsym() for system libraries (eg.: libresolv) on iOS?

Tags: ios, dlopen, dlsym, libresolv

Is this allowed to use dlopen() and dlsym() for system libraries (eg.: libresolv) on iOS?

Thanks for you answer in advance!

Comment: There's nothing stopping you, but also little reason to use them.  There's no concept of a plugin on iOS, linking is painless, and DyLibs are still a dream.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, and **theoretically,** it is allowed: it's in the POSIX API. (You can use *any* function from the C and POSIX standard library.)

However, `dlopen()` is often used for "cheating", i. e. for circumventing Apple's static analysis (because then you can obfuscate the name of private functions in private frameworks), so if they don't bother finding out what exactly you are using it for, then your app may be rejected. So you'd better directly link against the library instead.